# How to get a specific item from JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, web

I have a collection in a JSON file, when I access it by http://localhost:5000/product/ I see it, but when I try to get a specific product from it, like http://localhost:5000/product/1 I see nothing but [], what could be a possible solution to this?

I expect the output of http://localhost:5000/product/1 to be
{
"Id": 1,
"name": "Milk",
"Quantity": 100,
"Unit_coast": 2000
}

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does your API able to handle route for `http://localhost:5000/product/1` perform any filtering when receiving Id?

Comment: Yeah, when I call http://localhost:5000/product/Id?=1 I get [
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "name": "Milk",
    "Quantity": 100,
    "Unit_coast": 2000
  }
]

Comment: Would you post your API source code?

Comment: I think is better to show your implementation for the API on how you get the value from path and filtering. Unclear whether you are using which API framework like Node.JS, ASP.NET/ASP.NET Core API and etc.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server I'm using this json server for now

Comment: And the documentation on the site says if I use /1 in the end I should get the first object in the JSON

Comment: I suspect it could be the case-sensitive issue. `id` and `Id` may treat differently. Have you try to change the `Id` name to `id` (small-letter)?

Comment: Omg, Yeah, that worked out, I would never have guessed that was the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

jsut note that the filter method will always return an array - ieither use an index or use find()

as per Berlin Johns. M answer - but with an index on the return

```
function getProductById(productId) {
  const filteredProducts = products.filter(item => item.Id === productId);
   return filteredProducts[0];
 }
```

or use find to return the indidivudal item

```
function getProductById(productId) {
   return products.find(item => item.Id === productId);
}
```

and if you want to use more current arrow function

```
getProductById(productId) => products.find(item => item.Id === productId)
```

Answer (score 0):

create get productById new API end point

the logic :

```
function getProductById(productId) {
  const filteredProducts = products.filter(item => item.Id === productId);
  return filteredProducts;
}
```

Comment: jsut note that the filter method will always return an array - ieither use an index or use find()